# how can I retrieve instantiated objects of particular class in java?

Tags: java

For instance,

```
// Object 1
SensorMeasurement tempSDSMInfo1 = new SensorMeasurement("temperatureMeasurement", tempSDStruct, "SensorDriver", "TemperatureSensor");

// Object 2
SensorMeasurement tempSDSMInfo2 = new SensorMeasurement("temperatureMeasurement", tempSDStruct, "SensorDriver", "TemperatureSensor");

//Object 3
SensorMeasurement tempSDSMInfo3 = new SensorMeasurement("temperatureMeasurement", tempSDStruct, "SensorDriver", "TemperatureSensor");
```

Now later in the  program , **I want to retrieve all the  instantiated objects of a  particular class ?**

**I do not want to store them  in collection. Is there any other method?**

Comment: It sounds like you want to form a collection of objects.  Why do you not want to store them in a collection?

Comment: Do you want to find references for profiling or debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really any other method. The best practice approach to this problem is to use a factory for SensorMeasurement, or a manager class. Then you will be able to reference them later through the factory or manager and have actions done in the factory or manager as well allowing for a centralized logic center.

Comment: There is actually another method, via instrumentation, but I doubt it is what he is looking for.

Comment: @baba : can you explain instrumentation Method, if you can?

Comment: Well, basically, if you use an IDE, you have noticed that there is a possibility, when in debug mode, to see which classes have been loaded by the jvm, how many objects, etc. This is, of course, done on a snapshot at the current time. So if you find a way too hook into the debigging, you are set. Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html. As it states, instrumentation can give you information about the stats of the current jvm. I personally find that for the problem you described a factory would be sufficient (and less complex)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly in the Java language -- your only option is to store the desired object references in a collection.

For example, you could design your class as such:

```
public class SensorMeasurement {
  protected static Set<SensorMeasurement> allMeasurements = new HashSet();
  private SensorMeasurement(...) { }
  public static buildSensorMeasurement(String s, Object x, ...) {
    SensorMeasurement sm = new SensorMeasurement(s, x, ...);
    allMeasurements.add(sm);
    return sm;
  }
  public static Set<SensorMeasurement> getAllSensorMeasurements() {
    return new HashSet<SensorMeasurement>(allMeasurements);
  }
}
```

This way users of your class must use the "buildSensorMeasurement" factory method which will automatically add each instance to the collection which you can use as desired.